# If a Set $A= \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 \}$, how many subsets are there containing the elements $3$,$4$,$5$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Set $A= \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 \}$, how many subsets are there containing the elements $3$, $4$, $5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2^7$

You need sets of the form $\{3,4,5\dots \}$

Now apart from $\{3,4,5\}$ you have $\{1,2,6,7,8,9,10\}$, You can choose any subset of
$\{1,2,6,7,8,9,10\}$ and add it to $\{3,4,5\}$ to get the type of sets you want to count and the number of subsets of $\{1,2,6,7,8,9,10\}$ is $2^7$, hence it is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Any subset of $A$ containing $\{3,4,5\}$ will be of the form $\{3,4,5\}\cup S$ where $S\subseteq\{1,2,6,7,8,9,10\}$. How many choices are there for $S$?